# Partial View file uploads

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to figure out how to store multiplie files using a partial view. A screenshot of the partial view can be seen
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH6r2.png).

The partial view itself works perfectly as long as I use regular form inputs. Storing a file however is a bit more complex. Since I'm using Entity First, I'm just storing a reference to the file instead of the actual file itself.
This works fine for a single file. The byte reference gets stored to my database and I can generate a link to the file in a view which displays all the properties of a certain record.
However, I'm clueless on how I should tackle this if I want multiple uploads. One for each added row.

I'm also not sure how I should target a seperate field of a certain row through jQuery as all rows get generated dynamically, but that's a different issue.

### Relevant code:

**POST action of my controller:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateSrv([Bind(Include = "ID,CreationTimestamp,EditTimestamp,requestStatus,Requester,Reponsible,DeliveryDate,Project,CostCenter, MailCounter, ExtendedOrders")] Request request, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                if (upload.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                    upload.SaveAs(path);

                    using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
                    {
                        request.ExtendedOrders.ToArray()[0].File = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
                    }
                }                    
            }

            request.CreationTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
            request.EditTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
            request.RequestStatus = "Initial";
            request.RequestType = "Services";
            db.requests.Add(request);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(request);
    }
```

**Controller method which adds rows to my partial view using AJAX:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddOrderRowExtended()
    {
        OrderExtended order = new OrderExtended();
        order.Units = GetSelectListItems(GetUnitsFromDB());
        order.Unit = "PC";
        order.Currencies = GetSelectListItems(GetCurrenciesFromDB());
        order.Currency = "European Euro";
        return PartialView("~/Views/Orders/OrderExtendedCreate.cshtml", order);
    }
```

**I then call the partial view in my "main" view. The addOrder buttons adds more rows dynamically:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateSrv", "Requests", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<div class="form-horizontal">
... some fields of my Request model...

            <tbody id="OrderZone">
            @foreach (var row in Model.ExtendedOrders)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Orders/OrderExtendedCreate.cshtml", row);
            }
        </tbody>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="button" id="addOrder">Add row</button>
    <br />
    <div class="body-content">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

**My OrderExtended model:**

```
public class OrderExtended
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }


   ....

    [NotMapped]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Quotation { get; set; }

    public byte[] File { get; set; }

    //FK
    public int RequestRefId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RequestRefId")]
    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
}
```

**OrderExtendedCreate.cshtml**

```
@model RFP_MVC.Models.OrderExtended
 


<tr class="editorRow">
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("ExtendedOrders"))
    {
        <td class="col-md-2">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Material, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "input-sm form-control" } })</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "input-sm form-control" } })</td>
        <td class="col-md-2">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Unit, Model.Units, new { id = "Unit", @class = "input-sm form-control select2" })</td>
        <td class="col-md-2">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PurchGroup, Model.PurchGroupList, "Select...", new { @class = "input-sm form-control" })</td>
        <td class="col-md-2">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-default" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </span>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Vendor, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "Vendor" , @class = "input-sm form-control" } })
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-1">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.OrderingCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "input-sm form-control" } })</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "input-sm form-control" } })</td>
        <td class="col-md-1">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Currency, Model.Currencies, new { id = "Currency", @class = "input-sm form-control select2" })</td>
        <td class="col-md-2">
            <span class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-file glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"><input type="file" name="upload"></span>
        </td>
    }
</tr>
```

Thanks in advance

### Updated with solution:

**Changed my POST method**

1. Changed the parameter to an IEnumerable (as suggested by  ramiramilu):

   IEnumerable  files
2. Loop through all the files and process them:

```cs
int fileIndex = 0;
foreach (HttpPostedFileBase upload in files)
{
    if (upload != null && upload.ContentLength > 0)
    {   
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploads"), fileName);
        upload.SaveAs(path);

        using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(upload.InputStream))
        {
            request.ExtendedOrders.ToArray()[fileIndex].File = reader.ReadBytes(upload.ContentLength);
        }

        fileIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try by expecting IEnumerable - `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> upload`. also show us your `OrderExtendedCreate.cshtml` input file html markup.

Comment: Have your tried by `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> upload`?

Comment: Yes I have but as you can see, my partial view just holds a single file upload for each row. I don't want 1 row with multiple file uploads. I've tried your suggestion but only the first file gets uploaded.

Comment: Do you want to upload multiple files? or upload one file at a time? If you want to upload multiple files, the you need to expect `IEnumerable`. So simply, multiple `<input type="file" name="upload">` can upload all files at a time if you expect `IEnumerable,HttpPostedFileBase` upload` on your action. check this tutorial - http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/287/uploading-multiple-files-with-asp-net-mvc

Comment: You're right, it did the job but I'm having some issues with the BinaryReader. It only saves the reference of the first file.

Comment: Obviously, because you are not running a `foreach` on `upload` to iterate all the files and save them. Do a foreach and let me know if that solves the  issue.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks a lot! Working as intended now. I updated the code. You should post your comment as an answer so i can accept it as the correct solution. Thanks again.

Comment: I am glad, I solved your problem. Posted the same as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to upload multiple files, the you need to expect `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> upload` as a parameter to your Action. Once you get `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> upload`, use `foreach` and save each file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for uploading the file using partial view.
Create a file upload controller.

```
public class FileUploadController : Controller
 {
     //
     // GET: /FileUpload/

     public ActionResult Index()
     {
         return View();
     }
     public ActionResult UploadFile()
     {
         var httpPostedFileBase = Request.Files["FileName"];
         if (httpPostedFileBase != null && httpPostedFileBase.ContentLength > 0)
         {
             string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(httpPostedFileBase.FileName);
             string path1 = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Server.MapPath("~/SavedFiles"),  extension);
             if (System.IO.File.Exists(path1))
                 System.IO.File.Delete(path1);

             httpPostedFileBase.SaveAs(path1);
         }
         ViewData["Status"] = "Success";
         return View("Index");
     }
 }
```

You main view where partial view exists.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
//like wise you can call the fileupload partial view in multiple views
        @Html.Partial("_FileUpload")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your partial goes like this..

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("UploadFile","FileUpload",FormMethod.Post,new{enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <input type="file" name="FileName" id="file" style="width:240px"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
}
```

You can also view this article..

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Hope this will help you.
thanks